# What is the easiest way to play webm in Safari? Perian doesn't work

Tags: macos, safari, audio

I want to play webm in my website but I don't know why it doesn't play. I installed Perian and ffmpeg but none helps. Is there any simple pluging/codec as the one existing for IE?
[image]

Well it actually plays the sound I don't hear anything! While I hear it in other browsers.
I also tried the following code but yet I can't hear the audio in Safari https://code.google.com/p/webm/downloads/detail?name=WebM%20Component%20Installer.pkg

Comment: Did you also try [newer forks of Perian](https://github.com/MaddTheSane/perian)?